# GridView is not displayed even after databind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a GridView on my page that I want to bind data to, and do some sorting before the GridView is displayed but nothing is displayed. Below is my code:

```
  Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow

    ' define the table's schema

    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("PP", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("-", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Distance", GetType(String)))


    Dim i As Integer = 0


    ' Now Create a loop that Add data into datagridview and sort by shortest distance

    For Each r As System.Guid In arrid
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("PP") = ResolveUrl(arrpic(i))
        dr("-") = Arrnames(i).ToString & " (" & arrage(i) & ")" & vbCrLf & arrgender(i) & " from " & arrlocation(i) & vbCrLf & arrcomments(i)
        dr("Distance") = arrdistance(i)

        i = +1
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = dt.DataSet
    GridView1.DataBind()
    'SortDirection data by shortest distance
    'GridView1.Sort("Distance", SortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: simple thing is set break point and check whether data table or data set is null or not...

Comment: `GridView1.DataSource = dt`

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar. I tried to count tables using this line: MsgBox(dt.DataSet.Tables.Count), but I got the Object reference not set to an instance of an object message, suggesting no table exist. I have no idea Why?

Comment: @OneFineDay. I tried that before and it did not work

Comment: dt.Rows.Add(dr) you are missing refer Tim's Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GridView` is not displayed because it's empty.

You haven't added the new rows to the `DataTable`, therefore either use `table.Rows.Add(newRow)` or [`table.Rows.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wwak56(v=vs.110).aspx) instead which returns the already added (empty) row:

```
For Each r As System.Guid In arrid
    Dim dr = dt.NewRow() ' empty row not added yet
    dr("PP") = ResolveUrl(arrpic(i))
    dr("-") = Arrnames(i).ToString & " (" & arrage(i) & ")" & vbCrLf & arrgender(i) & " from " & arrlocation(i) & vbCrLf & arrcomments(i)
    dr("Distance") = arrdistance(i)
    dt.Rows.Add(dr) ' now added
    i = +1
Next
```

or

```
For Each r As System.Guid In arrid
    Dim dr = dt.Rows.Add() ' empty row now already added
    dr("PP") = ResolveUrl(arrpic(i))
    dr("-") = Arrnames(i).ToString & " (" & arrage(i) & ")" & vbCrLf & arrgender(i) & " from " & arrlocation(i) & vbCrLf & arrcomments(i)
    dr("Distance") = arrdistance(i)
    i = +1
Next
```

I prefer the second way if possible, it saves one line and prevents issues like this.